# How to find matrix representing a linear transformation?$T(a+bi,x+yi)=(a-b-y,x-2y+b,y-b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

I solved this one example like this :

$$T(a,b,c)=(a+2b,3c-a)$$

Here I written each vetor as basis of $(a,b,c)$ and got: $(a[1,-1],b[2,0],c[3,0])$

and the answer is the matrix : $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &2  &0 \\ 
-1 &0  &3 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

I can't understand how to apply this principle however for this exercise: $T(a+bi,x+yi)=(a-b-y,x-2y+b,y-b)$

The answer: $\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
0 &1 \\ 
0 &0 
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

how can I reach this solution? I think I know how to solve when there is a linear transformation with simple variables like a,b,c but here I have $a+bi,x+yi$

Comment: I am confused. What is the field that you are working with? Is it $\mathbb R$? Or $\mathbb C$? Or some other field?

Comment: it is not stated in the ex. itself. does it change the solution if it's complex or not?

Comment: The fact that the answer is a matrix with $3$ rows and $2$ columns suggsts that $T$ is a linear map from $\mathbb C^2$ into $\mathbb C^3$. There is a problem however: $T$ is **not** $\mathbb C$-linear. And if we see $T$ as a $\mathbb R$-linear map, then the matrix should have $4$ columns instead of $2$.